# Convert JSON with a ton of values under each (property? object?) to CSV with many rows is returning all values in one string

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I'm trying to use PowerShell to convert a json with the following format:

```
{"Value1":[89,91,88,71,59],"Value2":[53,58,54,53,58]}
```

To a CSV with the following format:

```text
Value1,Value2
89,53
91,58
88,54
71,53
59,58
```

The issue I'm running into is that this code that I've cobbled together

```
Get-Content 'C:\test\test.json' | ConvertFrom-Json | 
select  @{n='value1';e={-split $_.value1}},
        @{n='value2';e={-split $_.value2}} |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation 'C:\test\test.csv'
```

is making a CSV with the following format:

```text
Value1,Value2
89 91 88 71 59,53 58 54 53 58
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what I could do here? I'm really new to PowerShell and I'm getting pretty lost. I've read a ton of similar items on here and other sites, but none that exactly fit the issue I'm running into.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be more sophisticated solutions but at least for this simple example the following snippet works I think:

```
$Var = '{"Value1":[89,91,88,71,59],"Value2":[53,58,54,53,58]}' | ConvertFrom-Json 

$Var.Value1.Count
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Var.Value1.Count; $i++) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Value1 = $Var.Value1[$i]
        Value2 = $Var.Value2[$i]
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Value1 Value2
------ ------
    89     53
    91     58
    88     54
    71     53
    59     58
```

Comment: you can store the ouput of the for loop directly into a variable like `$csvObject = for ($i ...` and then convert that to csv: `$csvObject | convertto-csv`

Comment: It should be noted that this solution only works if both arrays `Value1` and `Value2` are of same length.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. How would I integrate this to actually pull in data from my json files? They do vary in how many rows they would result in.

Comment: @zett42 You're totally right. And the elements are actually totally unrelated to each other before. After this *conversion* there is a kind of relation then.

Comment: @PerpetuallyConfused Then the output format you choose might not be appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Olaf sorry I realize I wasn't clear: Value1 and Value2 will always have the same amount of rows as each other, but they will vary file-to-file.

Comment: Ah ... ok. That doesn't matter as we use the `.count` property of the array to determine the amount of elements ... or did I get it wrong now?  ;-)  You may try it with your actual production data.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it helped.